# Algorithm/function that clusters based off of weights of each node?

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, function

Say I have the following:

```
A 2
B 2
C 2
D 6
E 12
F 3
G 3
```

I want a function that takes in # of desired groups, and creates a "cluster" based on the #/weight. So for example, if the # of desired groups is 4, then it could return something like:

```
(A, B, C), (D), (F, G),  (E)

A+B+C = 6
D = 6
F + G = 6
E = 12
```

Is there some algorithm/function that allows me get get at such a result? Is there some kind of ideal method?

Comment: Take a look at [K-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you want to collect all nodes with the same weight into separate clusters? What if the number of clusters is not the same as the number of unique weights? Or do you want the aggregate weights of the clusters to be the same? (Then E in your example is not a good cluster.)

Comment: As much as possible, aggregate weights of the clusters to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like evenly grouping jobs according to their weights to be distributed over n threads.

For small numbers of jobs combinatorics may be a way to go however if you have thousands of jobs to be grouped and spread over hundreds of threads, most definitely combinatorics is not viable.

So my approach would be a much simpler but a two phase solution. The first phase returns an almost perfect result and the second phase tries to bring it to a perfection.

Due to my limited time i will just implement the first phase now and leave the second phase to the next few days. At the meantime please take it as a study and try to implement it yourself. yourself.

The idea of the first phase is very simple.

1. Sort the jobs in descending order (so the heavy jobs get inserted
   first and lighter ones are used for balancing)
2. Find the lightest chunk.
3. Insert the first job to the found chunk.
4. Find the lightest chunk.
5. Insert the next job to the found chunk and carry on with Step 4.

This is how i implemented;

```js
function chunkJobs(js,cc){ // jobs and chunk count as arguments
  var init = [...Array(cc)].map(_ => ({"jobs": [], "weight": 0}));
  return js.sort((a,b) => b.weight - a.weight)
           .reduce(function (cs,j){
                     var c = cs.reduce((p,c) => p.weight < c.weight ? p : c);
                     c.jobs.push(j.id);
                     c.weight += j.weight;
                     return cs;
                   }, init);
}

var jobs   = [{id: "A", weight: 2},
              {id: "B", weight: 2},
              {id: "C", weight: 2},
              {id: "D", weight: 6},
              {id: "F", weight: 3},
              {id: "G", weight: 3}],
    result = chunkJobs(jobs,3);
console.log(result)
```

So as you see the output is

```
[ { jobs: [ 'G', 'B' ], weight: 5 },
  { jobs: [ 'F', 'A', 'C' ], weight: 7 },
  { jobs: [ 'D' ], weight: 6 } ]
```

As i have mentioned before, although this may not seem to be the ideal solution for large number ob jobs it will be very close enough to the ideal. For example lets change the data to have 97 jobs each with a random weight chosen among 0 - 20 and add into the mix 3 very heavy jobs `{"id": 98, "weight": 113},{"id": 99, "weight": 63},{"id": 100, "weight": 91}`

```js
function chunkJobs(js,cc){ // jobs and chunk count as arguments
  var init = [...Array(cc)].map(_ => ({"jobs": [], "weight": 0}));
  return js.sort((a,b) => b.weight - a.weight)
           .reduce(function (cs,j){
                     var c = cs.reduce((p,c) => p.weight < c.weight ? p : c);
                     c.jobs.push(j.id);
                     c.weight += j.weight;
                     return cs;
                   }, init);
}

var jobs   = [...Array(97)].map((_,i) => ({"id": i+1, "weight": ~~(Math.random()*20)})).concat({"id": 98, "weight": 113},{"id": 99, "weight": 63},{"id": 100, "weight": 91});
    result = chunkJobs(jobs,16);
console.log(result);
```

Something like this

```
[ { jobs: [ 50, 91, 40, 33, 75, 41, 32 ], weight: 67 },
  { jobs: [ 70, 1, 20, 19, 30, 93, 97 ], weight: 67 },
  { jobs: [ 59, 8, 64, 29, 78, 13, 68 ], weight: 67 },
  { jobs: [ 17, 66, 65, 2, 73, 67, 14 ], weight: 67 },
  { jobs: [ 60, 43, 11, 84, 45, 35, 56 ], weight: 67 },
  { jobs: [ 90, 77, 21, 18, 9, 34, 37 ], weight: 67 },
  { jobs: [ 52, 5, 42, 69, 86, 72, 46 ], weight: 68 },
  { jobs: [ 95, 85, 54, 48, 38, 61, 88 ], weight: 68 },
  { jobs: [ 79, 82, 92, 31, 74, 25, 15 ], weight: 68 },
  { jobs: [ 87, 44, 58, 47, 51, 4 ], weight: 67 },
  { jobs: [ 26, 22, 49, 10, 39, 27, 7, 96, 71, 89, 55, 23 ], weight: 67 },
  { jobs: [ 6, 83, 28, 53, 63, 81, 36 ], weight: 68 },
  { jobs: [ 76, 62, 12, 24, 94, 80, 57 ], weight: 68 },
  { jobs: [ 99, 3, 16 ], weight: 69 },
  { jobs: [ 100 ], weight: 91 },
  { jobs: [ 98 ], weight: 113 } ]
```

Yet we will not be satisfied and carry on to iron the result over in the second phase. As a hint on second phase.. i don't think there is anything we can do with the threads resolved with a single job (like the last two in the above example) but for the remaining, a dynamical programming approach which relies on swapping jobs among threads according to the thread weight differences is possibly one good way to start with.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, filter out any values greater than 6. But there's a problem here.

Because you're required to have the result of the addition of all operands within a group to be 6, it's not possible to get arbitrary numbers of groups from a small set with a limited number of operands. You can produce different combinations of operands within a group, but this requires that the addition of all operands within a group yield 6. The exception as I see in your example from operands that are greater than or equal to 6, those operands formed their own groups (e.g, E and D).

It's like you have two 2's, one 3 and only one 1, how many 7's can you get from these numbers in different combinations by using unique operands within each group?

```
A = 2
B = 2 
C = 3 
D = 1
```

---

```
A          = 2
B          = 2 
C          = 3 
D          = 1
```

The above operands < 7

Let's permute these operands:

```
A + B      = 4 
A + C      = 3
A + D      = 3 
A + B + C  = 7
A + B + D  = 5 
A + C + D  = 6
B + C      = 5
B + D      = 3 
B + C + D  = 6
C + D      = 4
```

The answer is only one group that when we add all its operands we get 7. This group, consists of three operands `A + B + C`.

This the case in your desired algorithm. Although, sometimes you could obtain arbitrary numbers of groups, this is not guaranteed all the time even if you use operands that were used in other groups, just like the above example, there's only exactly one group that when we add all its operands we get 7.

Also, addition is commutative (A + B = B + A), so I didn't include `B + A`, `C + B`, `D + C`,...

Therefore, you can obtain only one group given the above set that when we add all its operands, we get 7. It's not only the uniqueness of the operands within a group which is problematic; it's also the nature of the limited set of values that we have that prevents us from getting arbitrary # number of groups.